# Azure VM templates

Tags: azure, templates, virtual-machine

So, I exported a VM template and I'm trying to build more VMs based on that template.

How can I define the subscription, resource group and region in the template or in the parameters file?

Comment: Are you using ARM? Could you share the relevant template and/or parameters details? If you use Az PowerShell or Azure CLI for the deployment, then the subscription is taken from your login context and the resourcegroup is passed through the command execution ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-8.2.0 ) - the region can be specified in the template/parameters under the "location": "string" parameter, See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use Azure Powershell to Deploy Virtual Machine, I have reproduced in my environment and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-1) :***

***Firstly if you donot have a resourcegroup create it using below cmdllet:***

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'rithwik' -Location 'EastUS'
```

(rithwik- Resourcegroup name)

[image]

***Then you need to try below cmdlet for deploying VM:***

```
New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName 'myResourceGroup' `
    -Name 'myVM' `
    -Location 'East US' `
    -VirtualNetworkName 'myVnet' `
    -SubnetName 'mySubnet' `
    -SecurityGroupName 'myNetworkSecurityGroup' `
    -PublicIpAddressName 'myPublicIpAddress' `
    -OpenPorts 80,3389
```

***After giving the command type your username and password as below:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***References of Code taken from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell#code-try-1

***In Portal:***

[image]